# How do I get the HTML content between two IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, outerhtml, nextuntil

This is my js code:

```
    $("tr[id^=list2ghead_]").each(function(){
                    j = i+1;
                    id_name = $(this).attr("id");
                    id_name_lenght = id_name.length;
                    if (i >= 10){
                        id_name = id_name.substr(0, id_name_lenght-2);
                    }else{
                        id_name = id_name.substr(0, id_name_lenght-1);
                    }
                    html = $("#"+id_name+i).nextUntil("#"+id_name+j).outerHTML;
                    $("#"+id_name+i).nextUntil("#"+id_name+j).remove();
                    html = "<div class='content'>"+html+"</div>";
                    $(html).insertAfter("#"+id_name+i);
                    i++;
 });
```

I want to get the HTML content between two IDs. After that I want to add to this HTML to a `div` with a class "content", remove the exiting HTML, and insert after an ID the HTML the new `div`. Now `outerHtml` returns `undefined`. What should I do ?

This is htnml code generated by jQgrid plugin:
[image]

Comment: Please show the HTML in your question.

Comment: the html code is generated by a jQuery plugin,but I can post a picture of it

Comment: you can copy from view page source :)

Comment: all of the html code is generated by the plugin with js , so it does not appear in the source code

Comment: Are the two ids on the same dom level or several different levels?

Comment: @PabloKarlsson look it picture, it is on the same level, thats the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`.outerHTML` is not a property of a jQuery selection.

Here is a way to move a selection from one place to another :

```
var $div = $('<div class="content"></div>');
var $selection = $("#"+id_name+i).nextUntil("#"+id_name+j);
$div.append($selection).insertAfter("#"+id_name+i);
```

Comment: it got this : HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and Javascript outerHTML property. If both nodes are at the same level:

```
var theHtml = "";
var id1 = "beginId";
var id2 = "endId";
var $node = $("#" + id1);
var nodes = new Array();
while($node.attr("id") != id2)
{
    nodes.push($node);
    theHtml += $node.get(0).outerHTML;
    $node = $node.next();
}
nodes.push($node); // Edit: also add the second node to the list
theHtml += $node.get(0).outerHTML; // Get the HTML of node with id2

$.each(nodes, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});

$(".content").attr("id","theHtml").html(theHtml);
```

This will include the html of both nodes with id1 and id2.

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: $node.get(...) is undefined

Comment: It means that $("#" + id1) did not find anything because the id might be wrong (or the element does not exists yet), or that $node.next() did not find anything, in which case the while loop did not end before reaching the last sibbling because id2 is wrong or because the element with id2 is not on the same level as id1.

Comment: Are you developping in Wordpress or using some other kind of libraries ? If so, try using `var $node = jQuery("#" + id1);` instead, if it works, my previous comment does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery object doesn't have outerHTML property. For getting the property you can use the prop method. `$collection.prop('outerHTML')`. Note that `prop` as getter returns value of the first matched element, so you should iterate through the collection and read the properties individually.

```
var outerHTML = $("#"+id_name+i).nextUntil("#"+id_name+j).map(function() {
    return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join('');
```

Note that `div` element can't have `tr` children!

You could also get the next element using indexes and `eq` method:

```
var $col = $("tr[id^=list2ghead_]");

$col.each(function(i) {
   var $next = $col.eq(i + 1);
   var $between = $(this).nextUntil($next); //.filter('.jqrow');
   var outerHTML = $between.map(function() {
        return this.outerHTML;
  }).get().join(''); 

  console.log(outerHTML);    
});
```

Comment: I got this : ReferenceError: id_name is not defined

Comment: is there a function in Jquery similar to outerHTML ?

Comment: @Chester I don't know how you have implemented the first snippet in your code.  You define it here `id_name = $(this).attr("id");`, don't you? No, jQuery doesn't have such method. `outerHTML` is a property. as I have stated `prop` can read the property for you. What's wrong with using the `map` method? If the logic couldn't return the expected collection, you can try the second snippet using the `eq` and probably `filter` methods.

Comment: ok, my fault i did not put into my each function your code:) , but where i should include this part:<div class='content'></div>, because i want to put the content of the two ids into a div with the class content ? btw: thx for helping me

Comment: @Chester You are welcome. "Note that `div` element can't have `tr` children!" You can get the `td` children's content and then set the `innerHTML` of `div` elements. Is this what you are after?

Comment: hmmm thats should be problem, so what does it should have tr children?

Comment: @Chester Sorry, I didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: is there an html tag, which can have tr children ?

Comment: @Chester Yes, `table` element can have!